# Getting inspector tab of script when it is slid into an inspector field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is all the elements of my problem: i have a "ShotPattern" class that is supposed to define a bullet pattern that would be shot by a firearm.

A Shot Pattern in code:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class ShotPattern : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Projectile info")]
[SerializeField]
private GameObject projectile;
[SerializeField]
private AMovementPattern projectileMovementPattern;

    [Header("Pattern shape info")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 startVector = Vector2.zero;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 endVector = Vector2.zero;
    [SerializeField]
    private int projectileAmount = 1;
    [SerializeField]
    private float timeBetweenShots = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speedIncrementBetweenShots = 0;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        Shoot(transform.position);
    }
    
    public virtual void Shoot(Vector3 origin)
    {
        float angleDelta = (Vector2.SignedAngle(startVector,endVector)) / projectileAmount;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < projectileAmount ; i++)
        {
            GameObject currentProjectile = Instantiate(projectile,origin,quaternion.identity);
            StraightMovePattern currentMovePattern = currentProjectile.AddComponent<StraightMovePattern>();
            currentMovePattern.direction = startVector.normalized;
        }
    }

}
```

A ShotPattern in inspector

[image: A ShotPattern in inspector]

I also have a few classes that define movement patterns for the resulting projectiles (move straight, in a sine wave, etc), these classes all inherit from the "AMovementPattern" Class.

The AMovementPattern abstract class in code:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public abstract class AMovementPattern : MonoBehaviour
{
    /**
     * Direction of the movement pattern. (is down by default since we assume movement patterns are mostly used by enemies)
     */
    [Header("General movement info")]
    public Vector2 direction = Vector2.down;
    
    /**
     * Speed of the movement pattern.
     */
    [SerializeField]
    protected float speed = 1f;
    
    protected Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovementUpdate();
    }

    /**
     * Method to calculate the new position of the object based on the movement pattern and previous position.
     */
    protected virtual void MovementUpdate()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

A Movement pattern subclass in code:

```cs
public class StraightMovePattern : AMovementPattern
{
    protected override void MovementUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = direction * speed;
    }
}
```

A Movement pattern subclass in inspector

[image: A Movement pattern subclass in inspector]

As you can tell from the ShotPattern inspector tab i want to be able to give a MovementPattern script to the ShotPattern editor for it to add to the projectiles it will produce on instanciation.
Unity won't let me just slide one of my MovePattern subclasses into the "AMovePattern" field, I am guessing it is because this field wants an instance of those classes with its parameters already set , is there a way to make it so that i could slide any of the MovePattern scripts in there and have the the corresponding inspector tab appear?

I know that i could make an empty GameObject that holds a movement pattern script, and initialize the values of that movement script in this GameObjects editor, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having it in inspector where i can edit the overall pattern on the fly to test out different compositions, so i'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I'm not a C# person but try making `AMovementPattern` non-abstract.  Especially since Start and FixedUpdate have implementations.  It's really not abstract.
I also believe you need to implement all methods of the Abstract class - Start & FixedUpdate.  But again, I'm not a C# guy and can be completely wrong.

Comment: Your guess is right, first you need assign an instance to the field. To draw a MovePattern's inspector on the ShotPattern's inspector, you need to create a [DecoratorDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DecoratorDrawer.html) or [CustomEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html).

Comment: So it would be possible to edit the MovePattern using its inspector within the ShotPattern's inspector using a custom editor, effectively it would be exactly like editing a prefab instance via its inspector if i understand you correctly?

Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'll look into custom editors, did not know those were a thing, neat!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest add those changes make `MovementUpdate` abstract like this so you will need to always implement this method.

```
protected abstract void MovementUpdate();
```

The second I would separate data and execution of pattern to two separate classes. Then I would redo the ShootPattern like this.

```
[Header("Projectile info")]
[SerializeField]
private Projectile projectile;
[SerializeField]
private AMovementPattern projectileMovementPattern;

    public virtual void Shoot(Vector3 origin)
    {
        float angleDelta = (Vector2.SignedAngle(startVector,endVector)) / projectileAmount;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < projectileAmount ; i++)
        {
            var currentProjectile = Instantiate(projectile,origin,quaternion.identity);
            currentProjectile.Init(projectileMovementPattern, startVector.normalized);
        }
    }
```

And I suggest you to use [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) to hold such a data.

Remark from a Unity/C# guy
It has nothing to do with a abstract class.

Comment: I might not be grasping what you suggest correctly, but would that enable me to edit the movementPattern in the inspector field? 

Aside from that i agree, a scriptable object would fit what i am trying to achieve with the class!

Comment: Short answer is yes it will.
The real answer 
The problem you have is that you using the component system in wrong way. You edit one component and then adding another to projectile. Value in one instance of a class(the thing you see in editor inspector) would affect other instances of this class.
So you either need to pass them to from one instance to a new one or just pass the edited instance as a data.

What I suggested it is for you to have Projectile  script that can move itself base on AMovementPattern it is initialized with and starting vector.